# cropperjs not show preview as expected

Tags: javascript, cropperjs

This is my code to init copperjs:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param input
 * @param files
 */
showImageEditor: function (input, files) {
    var cropper,reader,file,image;

    if (alertify) {
        alertify.confirm(
        ).set('onok', function (closeEvent) {
                if(cropper) {
                    var data = cropper.getData(true);
                    cropper.destroy();
                    cropper = null;
                    
                    //todo: save data
                }
            }
        ).set('oncancel', function (closeEvent) {
                if(cropper) {
                    cropper.destroy();
                    cropper = null;
                }
                if(image) {
                    image = null;
                }
            }
        ).set({
            message: '<div class="img-container">\n' +
                '  <div class="row">\n' +
                '    <div class="col-md-8">  \n' +
                '      <img id="image">\n' +
                '    </div>\n' +
                '    <div class="col-md-4">\n' +
                '      <div class="preview"></div>\n' +
                '    </div>\n' +
                '  </div>\n' +
                '</div>',
            title: "Title",
            transition: "zoom",
            labels: {
                ok: "OK",
                cancel: "CANCEL",
            },
            maintainFocus: false, 
            onshow: function () {
                image = document.querySelector('.image-modal #image');
                if (files && files.length > 0) {
                    file = files[0];
                    reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onloadend = function(e) {
                        image.src = reader.result;
                        cropper = new Cropper(image, {
                            //aspectRatio: 1,
                            viewMode: 3,
                            preview: '.preview',
                        });
                    };
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                }
            }
        }).show(true, 'image-modal');
    }
}
```

My css:

```
.alertify.image-modal .ajs-dialog {
    max-width: 90%;
    max-height: 90%;
}
.alertify.image-modal .ajs-body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.alertify.image-modal .img-container .row {
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.alertify.image-modal .img-container .row .col-md-8 {
    flex-basis: 60%;
}
.alertify.image-modal .img-container .row .col-md-4 {
    flex-basis: 40%;
}
.alertify.image-modal .img-container #image {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: fit-content;
}
.alertify.image-modal .img-container .preview {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
}
.alertify.image-modal .img-container .preview img {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

So preview is always:

```
element.style {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
}
```

And not cropped as is crop frame visible on original image.
Why? What is wrong?

Next problem is portrait image like this demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/x5gab4kp/
Image is over modal.

Landscape is OK like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/f71qangy/